# cannot handle object of type VECSXP?

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

When trying to use dplyr's n_distinct function on a dataset, I encountered this error:

```
cannot handle object of type VECSXP
```

What might be the cause of this error and how can I avoid it? I hope there is enough information here to answer the question, I would provide more information but I don't even know where to focus on.

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to provide few lines of your data using `dput` i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))` As the error indicates, your object may not be compatible with dplyr methods

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the response! my object is a data.table, perhaps that's not compatible with dplyr?

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the post.  Anyway, you got a solution where another case also result in the same error.  Probably, the function is not compatible within the dplyr

Comment: Use `uniqueN` from dev version of data.table, which works on lists too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your data look like, but I suspect you are trying to use `n_distinct` on a `list` when it expects a vector as input (`VECSXP` is the *C* representation of an *R* `list`):

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:3, 7, replace=TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(x)
df1$y <- list(x)
##
R> dplyr::n_distinct(df1$x)
[1] 3
##
R> dplyr::n_distinct(df1$y)
Error: cannot handle object of typeVECSXP
```

---

Where it seems that your error is being generated from [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/37124a7abc20df0c84bbbfc7ddc5de5af10a1099/src/dplyr.cpp):

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP n_distinct(SEXP x){
    int n = Rf_length(x) ;
    if( n == 0 ) return wrap(0) ;
    SlicingIndex everything(0, n);
    boost::scoped_ptr<Result> res( count_distinct_result(x) );
    if( !res ){
        stop( "cannot handle object of type %s", type2name(x) );
    }
    return res->process(everything) ;
}
```

---

Again, *still* not sure what your code looks like, but I assume you are doing something like

```
R> dplyr::n_distinct(Dt[,1,with=F])
#Error: cannot handle object of typeVECSXP
```

instead of

```
R> dplyr::n_distinct(Dt[[1]])
##[1] 2
```

and since the first case returns a `data.table` (and therefore a `list`),

```
R> Dt[,1,with=F]
   x
1: 1
2: 2
R> class(Dt[,1,with=F])
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

instead of an atomic vector,

```
R> Dt[[1]]
[1] 1 2
R> class(Dt[[1]])
[1] "integer"
```

you are getting an error.

---

```
library(data.table)
Dt <- data.table(x=1:2, y=3:4)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! my dataset is essentially a data table of character and numeric values (nonfactored), and I'm trying to call n_distinct on one column in the data table. It shouldn't be a list but maybe datatable is something different?